# Extract Workflow column value from AllUserData table

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-server, content-database

I have a SP 2010 content database and I am trying to extract list data from it. I cannot successfully restore the content database to a SP farm, that's why I am trying to directly retrieve the data from the raw SQL database.

The issue is that I am unable to retrieve the value of a SP workflow column (SP list column that is added automatically to the SP list when a workflow is associated to the list). See screenshot from SP user interface:

[image]

When I execute the following SQL statement in SQL management studio

```
select * from dbo.AllUserData where tp_listId = 'B356A25A-B2E3-44CC-B4FC-6C2E150B7697'
```

the result is the following:

[image]

I am 100% certain that the value of the SP column workflow1 is stored in the SQL column nvarchar3 (I am certain because I executed the same SQL statement before adding the SP column to the list, and nvarchar3 was empty).

So the question is, how do I decode these gibberish characters "钨ꆁ귖䧶憠콹姽㯠" programmatically and get to the string "In Progress"? It doesn't seem to be UTF8 or UTF16 or Base64.